# MVC3 razor how to handle button clicks for each of the dynamically created button sets

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

On my MVC3 razor view I have one "GetRecords" button.Upon clicking this button,it will post back and retrieve multiple sets of records .Depending on the number of record sets it will dynamically regenerate the view and show each set of records.It will also generate "save"  and "Delete" buttons against each set of records ,so that the user and review each recordset and can "save" or "delete" data from any of these record sets .

Here my question how to handle  button clicks here .Any suggestions

```
[Httppost]
 public ActionResult GetRecords(ContentsViewModel vmodel)
        {
         vmodel.GetRecords();

       return view(vmodel);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what it is you are trying to achieve but if you wanted to handle multiple buttons from a form then in the view you would need to give a name to each of the buttons.  For example:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="Get Records" name="getrecords"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" name="save"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" name="delete"/>
}
```

And then you can test for these values in the post action by using:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AppropriateActionNameHere(ContentsViewModel vmodel)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["getrecords"]))
    {
        vmodel.GetRecords();
    }
    else if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["save"]))
    {
        //save record processing here
    }
    else if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["delete"]))
    {
        //delete record processing here
    }
    return View(vmodel); //Or perform the appropriate redirect or whatever you need to perform
}
```

Another possiblity would be to have mutliple forms on the view where each form posts back to a different action.